# Sizeof(uint8_t*) is always 4?

Tags: c++

I create a vector of `uint_8t*` sometimes with 3, 4 or 5 bytes but when I make the `sizeof` my array, I always get 4. How can I solve this?

After creating my array I want to get the length of it.

Example:

```
uint_8t* u8;

u8[0]=...;
u8[1]=...;
```

`sizeof(u8)=4` instead of `2`.

`sizeof(uint8_t)` is `1`, I Al`o tried`sizeof(u8)/sizeof(u8[0])` and I get 4

Comment: do you have a vector or an array? I suppose you are taking the `sizeof` a pointer which is always the same

Comment: So how can I get how many bytes I have at uint_8t*

Comment: in your example there is no array only a pointer

Comment: Ok sorry yes its a pointer, how can I get how many bytes I have.

Comment: If you mean how to get the size of the allocated array via a pointer to it - you can't

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The question is unclear, because to create the array you need to know its size already before you create it

Comment: @mikelasesino you can't unless if you have another variable that holds it's size. use `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof(uint8_t*)` is the size of pointer. Which is typically 4 for 32-bit architectures and 8 for 64-bit architectures. Also typically this doesn't depend on the underlying structure (should be the same for uint8_t*, std::string*, long*, and so on), although this is not guaranteed.

`sizeof(uint8_t)` is 1 because that's what `uint8_t` is: a 1 byte.

It seems that you want to know the size of the memory which `uint8_t*` points at. **There is no way to do that given a pointer only.** You have to track the size manually. Typically by using [std::vector<uint8_t>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of raw pointers.

Comment: Mmm okay I understand. So how could I pass the allocated size? This pointer is the output of a function, and after I need this pointer and also the size..

Comment: @mikelasesino as I said: in general there's no way to do that. Unless this function does something special, like for example it guarantees that the size is always the same. Or maybe it guarantees that the the last element in the array is 0. Otherwise this is very badly written function and you are doomed to fail.